# Content on page disappears

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple script of code that reads a PHP file and when it get's changed it's supposed to say CHANGED on the page which I will change to refresh the page or change the content. For now, it shows the content, the function repeats once or twice and then it just shows nothing. Any help?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("../chat/real/chatserver.php", "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize("../chat/real/chatserver.php"));
fclose($handle);
$newcontents = $contents;
echo $contents;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
checkchanged();
function checkchanged() {
document.write("<?php $handle = fopen('../chat/real/chatserver.php', 'r');
$newcontents = fread($handle,filesize('../chat/real/chatserver.php'));fclose($handle);?>");
document.write("<?php if(!($contents==$newcontents)){echo 'Changed';} ?>");
setTimeout('checkchanged()',3000);
}
</script>
```

[Link to example](http://silmar.co.cc/main/test/)

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should move away from using `document.write()`, which is probably what your problem is related to. See how I rewrote your code, including using a reference to a function expression contained in a closure so it's all out of the global namespace: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/aPwaY/ Notice how `refresh()` calls itself on the last line, and that I have `setTimeout(refresh, 3000);` instead of a string representation of a function, which is bad practice and a potential security issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you can't include PHP in your JavaScript in order to execute it by the client. Yes, you can include PHP values, but that's it. Have a look at the source code in your browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
checkchanged();
function checkchanged() {
document.write("");
document.write("");
setTimeout('checkchanged()',3000);
}
</script>
```

As you can see, the function `document.write` gets called with an empty string `""`. This is because everything that is in `<?php ?>` gets executed on the server, not on the client, ***before*** the resulting page gets sent to the client.

Since every PHP code is parsed only once `$contents==$newcontents` will be `true`, so you'll never see `Changed`.

To achieve something like a chat server you'll need new http request. Have a look at AJAX.

Comment: What's wrong with his PHP code where it's at? It's funkily formatted, but it looks like all of the tags are closed.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Doesn't matter if his tags are closed. The logic in his script is completely ridiculous. He wants to use `checkchanged` in order to get new messages from his server. In order to achieve this he wants to get the content of a file by using PHP. But this PHP code will never be transferred to the client.

Comment: I see. Your opening statement is possibly misleading; you can put PHP markup within Javascript. I can see what you're saying now, but consider rephrasing that first sentence.

Comment: I can see your comments, maybe being a little nicer might help you. I'm not the best coder in the world and the whole reason for this website is to ask questions you do not to know the answers to. I asked my question to see why it wouldn't work you didn't need to go on about how it's ridiculous. So can I have an AJAX script that reads the file and checks if it is changed or are you telling me I have to look at going from a server like MySQL or something and going from there?

Comment: @user1456942: I am well aware that you can see my comments, but I didn't mean to be rude :/. Don't take the "ridiculous" statement personal, it was rather directed towards Jared's additional question and should be taken with a grain of salt. Yes, you can use an AJAX script that requests a page which contains the new messages. Those can be generated by a PHP script. If you want to use AJAX then you can either write it yourself, which is tedious, or use a JavaScript framework like jQuery. While MySQL or other databases aren't needed you should ask yourself whether it would be easier to use one.